# How to avoid fancybox to trigger once child element is clicked

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have applied fancybox to the parent element, but when i try to click a button inside it, it will also trigger the fancy box which is not the expected result

```
<div data-img-id="256" data-fancybox="" href="https://www.14.jpg" >
   <button class="btn btn--small js-image-selector-btn">Select</button>
</div>
```

so when i click button inside the parent, it is also triggering the fancybox, please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply prevent event event bubbling and/or prevent default action inside your click event:

```js
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```